# ¿Qué dimensión dar a la entrada de una red neuronal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redes-neuronales

Intento construir un red neuronal para juegar al [juego de Domineering](https://www.jasondavies.com/domineering/#5x5). Tengo una base de datos de juegos [que pueden obtener aqui](http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~cazenave/domineering.csv.zip). Estas son líneas que representan los juegos en las bandejas 8 * 8, luego el reverso en 8 * 8 luego 8 * 8 en las figuras que dicen qué jugada se jugó y finalmente la tabla correspondiente.

Por ejemplo, líneas de csv para una placa 2x2:

```
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
```

Para juegos 8*8 esto hace 256 cifras. Las dimensiones de la entrada son por lo tanto de 126 columnas para el board y su reverso, los demas son para el output.

Sin embargo cuando intento construir el red neuronal intento construir 12 nodos para 128 inputs parece que hay un problema con la primera capa `model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=128, activation='relu'))`

```
# model construction

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='sigmoid'))

print("compile")
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print("fit")
model.fit(X_test, Y_test, epochs=3, batch_size=10)
```

En efecto me da el siguiente value error :

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_27 to have shape (128,) but got array with shape (127,)
```

Y cuando intento reemplazar por 127, solo para ver me dice :

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_28_input to have shape (127,) but got array with shape (128,)
```

Aqui esta el entero codigo, que pueden obtener [sobre GitHub tambien](https://github.com/antoinecomp/domineering). Es el ipython notebook.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from timeit import default_timer as timer

import csv 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# we divide data.csv into train and tests 

with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
    plays = np.array(list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")))
    print(plays.shape)    
# We take the 126 first columns as input
df = pd.DataFrame(data=plays[0:28961,1:256])
# We take the 126 last columns as output
Y = pd.DataFrame(data=plays[0:28961,129:256])

#plays.reshape((64,64))

#board = np.reshape(plays, (8, 8))

df['split'] = np.random.randn(df.shape[0], 1)
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) <= 0.7

train_df = df[msk].fillna("sterby")
test_df = df[~msk].fillna("sterby")

# we take the 128 first columns has input
X_train = train_df.iloc[:,0:128].values
# we take the 128 last columns has input
y_train = train_df.iloc[:,129:].values
X_test = test_df.iloc[:,0:128].values
Y_test = test_df.iloc[:,129:].values

# Necesary Keras Importations

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.optimizers import Adam

# model construction

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='sigmoid'))

print("compile")
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print("fit")
model.fit(X_test, Y_test, epochs=3, batch_size=10)

print("evaluate")

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Y el error

```
compile 
fit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-8b0dc569bd70> in <module>()
      3 
      4 print("fit\n")
----> 5 model.fit(X_test, Y_test, epochs=3, batch_size=10)
      6 
      7 # evaluate the model

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    961                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    962                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 963                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
    964 
    965     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1628             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1629             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1630             batch_size=batch_size)
   1631         # Prepare validation data.
   1632         do_validation = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
   1478                                     output_shapes,
   1479                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1480                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1481         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1482                                                      self._feed_output_names)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    121                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    122                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 123                             str(data_shape))
    124     return data
    125 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_12 to have shape (128,) but got array with shape (127,)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea que tienes es que ante una entrada de 128, la red te devuelva una salida de 128 que sería la grilla de respuesta.

Si revisas las siguientes matrices de entrada y salida:

```
X_train.shape # (19660, 128)
y_train.shape # (19660, 127)
X_test.shape  # (8495, 128)
Y_test.shape  # (8495, 127)
```

Por lo que tus salidas son diferentes a lo que pides en la red, una vez arreglas esto la red puede entrenar.

No solo está ese error de dimensión ahi, pero si revisas `df` y `Y` puedes notar que tampoco cuadran.